# How to toggle visibility of multiple JSON overlays in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple JSON overlay files - Area 1 through 6.

I want to be able to control the visibility of the overlays using the radio button menu.

I've tried setting each overlay as a variable and adding an if else statement to toggle the visibility but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map Template</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

        #search {
            position:absolute;

        }

      #pac-input {
                    width:400px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            height: 40px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 300;


        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 320px;
        height: 40px;
        border-width: 2px;
          border: white;
          box-shadow: none;
          border-radius: 2px;
          box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px;
          font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
          font-weight: 400;
          color: gray;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
          color: black;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="search">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="search" placeholder="Search Any Address">
          </div>
      <form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">
        <input type="radio" id="area1" name="switch-two" checked/>
        <label for="area1">Area 1</label>

        <input type="radio" id="area2" name="switch-two"/>
        <label for="area2">Area 2</label>

        <input type="radio" id="area3" name="switch-two"/>
        <label for="area3">Area 3</label>

        <input type="radio" id="area4" name="switch-two"/>
        <label for="area4">Area 4</label>

        <input type="radio" id="area5" name="switch-two"/>
        <label for="area5">Area 5</label>

        <input type="radio" id="area6" name="switch-two"/>
        <label for="area6">Area 6</label>       
    </div>
</form>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">


      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 52.656963, lng: -112.506664},
          gestureHandling: 'greedy',
  mapTypeControl: false
        });



    var area1 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area2 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area3 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area4 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area5 = new google.maps.Data();

    area1.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/myw18');
    area2.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nkbn0');
    area3.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/cwnws');
    area4.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/106pnw');
    area5.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7lwmk');




if (area1.checked) {

    var area1 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area2 = null;
    var area3 = null;
    var area4 = null;
    var area5 = null;

  } else if (area2.checked) {

    var area1 = null;
    var area2 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area3 = null;
    var area4 = null;
    var area5 = null;

  } else if (area3.checked) {

    var area1 = null;
    var area2 = null;
    var area3 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area4 = null;
    var area5 = null;

  } else if (area4.checked) {

    var area1 = null;
    var area2 = null;
    var area3 = null;
    var area4 = new google.maps.Data();
    var area5 = null;

  } else if (area5.checked) {

    var area1 = null;
    var area2 = null;
    var area3 = null;
    var area4 = null;
    var area5 = new google.maps.Data();
  }





                map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
            return {
                  fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
                   strokeWeight: 1,
                   strokeColor: 'black',
                   fillOpacity: 0.4,
                   strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                   zIndex: 0
            };
        });


        // Infowindow
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    zIndex: 2
            });
            map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

            map.data.revertStyle();
            map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'black', zIndex: 1});

            var CDNAME  = event.feature.getProperty('CDNAME');
            var COLOR   = event.feature.getProperty('COLOR');

            infoWindow.setPosition( event.latLng );
            infoWindow.setOptions( {
                pixelOffset: {width: 0, height: -3}
            });

            infoWindow.setContent(
                    "CDNAME: <b>" + CDNAME + "</b><br />" + 
                    "COLOR: <b>" + COLOR + "</b>"
            );  
            infoWindow.open(map);   

         });

         map.data.addListener('clickout', function(event) {

            map.data.revertStyle();
            infoWindow.close();
         });

         map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {

            map.data.revertStyle();
            map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'black', zIndex: 1});               
         });



        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: 'https://www.adsforcarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/map-marker2.png',
              size: new google.maps.Size(50, 75),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 75)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

When the map loads I want only the Area1 to be visible since that radio option is checked by default.

When I choose another radio, Area4 for example, I want Area1 to become invisible and Area4 to become visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `map` property of the `Data` object when you want it rendered on the `map`.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.setMap):

> **setMap**
>   setMap(map)
>   **Parameters:**
>   map:  Map
>   Return Value:  None
>   Renders the features on the specified map. If map is set to null, the features will be removed from the map.

```
var area1 = new google.maps.Data();
var area2 = new google.maps.Data();
var area3 = new google.maps.Data();
var area4 = new google.maps.Data();
var area5 = new google.maps.Data();

area1.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/myw18');
area2.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nkbn0');
area3.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/cwnws');
area4.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/106pnw');
area5.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7lwmk');

setArea();

function setArea() {
  area1.setMap(document.getElementById('area1').checked ? map : null);
  area2.setMap(document.getElementById('area2').checked ? map : null);
  area3.setMap(document.getElementById('area3').checked ? map : null);
  area4.setMap(document.getElementById('area4').checked ? map : null);
  area5.setMap(document.getElementById('area5').checked ? map : null);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4c9eb5m7/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 52.656963,
      lng: -112.506664
    },
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  var area1 = new google.maps.Data();
  var area2 = new google.maps.Data();
  var area3 = new google.maps.Data();
  var area4 = new google.maps.Data();
  var area5 = new google.maps.Data();

  area1.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/myw18');
  area2.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nkbn0');
  area3.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/cwnws');
  area4.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/106pnw');
  area5.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7lwmk');

  setArea();

  function setArea() {
    area1.setMap(document.getElementById('area1').checked ? map : null);
    area2.setMap(document.getElementById('area2').checked ? map : null);
    area3.setMap(document.getElementById('area3').checked ? map : null);
    area4.setMap(document.getElementById('area4').checked ? map : null);
    area5.setMap(document.getElementById('area5').checked ? map : null);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area1'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area2'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area3'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area4'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area5'), 'click', setArea);

}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="switch-field">
    <input type="radio" id="area1" name="switch-two" checked/>
    <label for="area1">Area 1</label>

    <input type="radio" id="area2" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area2">Area 2</label>

    <input type="radio" id="area3" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area3">Area 3</label>

    <input type="radio" id="area4" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area4">Area 4</label>

    <input type="radio" id="area5" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area5">Area 5</label>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works! Is there a way to keep the setStyle in my code, because the current solution ignores that function for some reason

Comment: Did they work before?  You have to apply those to the data objects, if that doesn't help, then it probably should be a new question.